# How to create component scss with ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I can't link my scss to components in ionic 2 using the standard angular 2 :

```
styleUrls: ['form.component.scss']
```

How is it done ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ionic2 can take a bit of learning curve as they've redone a lot of how Angular2 works, but once you get used to it it's really fantastic...

For adding scss to components it's super easy, you just throw it into the folder with your TS/html and the ionic build gulp process takes care of the rest for you. So just kill that line for styleUrls and you'll be all set.

It does; however, jack with css inheritance some so you'll want to be careful how you set it up.

Comment: is it possible to add 2 scss files for 1 component? I want to add 2 files 1 file to left to right scss and other for right to left scss

Comment: yea Ionic will scrape for any .scss files and include them for you. If you want to switch between right to left and left to right though, there are probably better setups.I would search around for pre-packages solutions personally, check out http://rtlcss.com/